# i get compile error while using set_difference

Tags: c++, stl

```
std::set<std::string> tradedSymbolSet; 
//..
// tradedSymbols is filled
//..
std::set<std::string> symbols;
//...
// symbols is filled
//..

std::set_difference(tradedSymbolSet.begin(), tradedSymbolSet.end(), 
        symbols.begin(), symbols.end(), diffSet.begin());
```

i get this compile error:

> "error C2678: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)"

complaining about the set_difference function's usage. i couldn't get

Comment: did you forget to #include <string> ?

Comment: @Bathsheba : it is included..

Comment: Is `diffSet` `const`?

Comment: @Peter Wood: Good spot: that's where the smart money is.

Comment: @Bathsheba: `diffSet` could be *non-const* object of type `std::set` also. See my answer.

Comment: @PeterWood Is `diffSet` an `std::set`?  That's the most probably source of the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess `diffSet` is `std::set`. If so, that is the problem : `std::set` stores elements as const objects, which means the object pointed to by `std::set::iterator` is **read-only**. You cannot write to it.

Use `std::vector` and `std::back_inserter` as:

```
std::vector<std::string> diff;

std::set_difference(tradedSymbolSet.begin(), tradedSymbolSet.end(), 
         symbols.begin(), symbols.end(), std::back_inserter(diff));
```

Once you have `diff`, you can create an object `diffSet` as:

```
std::set<std::string> diffSet(diff.begin(), diff.end());
```

Or, insert elements to an existing set as:

```
std::set<std::string> existingDiffSet;
//some code...

existingDiffSet.insert(diff.begin(), diff.end());
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: You _can_ use the set functions on an `std::set`, although it isn't really as idiomatic as using them with sorted vectors.  If he really needs a set, and the use of `set_difference` is one of, this is the route I'd go.  If he's doing a lot of `set_...`, I'd recommend converting everything to `vector`, and keeping them sorted.

Comment: Well, you don't actually need a `std::vector` if you've come as far as looking at the insert iterators, a simple `std::inserter(diffSet, diffSet.end())` would have done, too.

Comment: @ChristianRau: I realized that now. Hope the readers read your comment (and James's answer which also mentions this).

Answer (score 3):

You don't show the definition of `diffSet`, but if, as its name
indicates, it is an `std::set`, you can't assign into it.  The
type of the object returned by the iterator is always const.
There's also the question of whether the elements you are
assigning to exist.  If they don't (`diffSet.size()` less than
the number of elements in the results), and the assignment were
allowed, you'd have undefined behavior (but likely a crash); if
they do, and the assignment was allowed, modifying an entry in
the `std::set` would likely inviolate internal invariants
regarding the order.

The usual use of the set functions is on sorted `std::vector`,
with an insertion iterator for the output:

```
std::vector<std::string> tradedSymbols;
//  fill tradedSymbols
std::sort( tradedSymbols.begin(), tradedSymbols.end() );
std::vector<std::string> symbols;
//  fill symbols
std::sort( symbols.begin(), symbols.end() );

std::vector<std::string> diffs;
std::set_difference( tradedSymbols.begin(), tradedSymbols.end(),
                     symbols.begin(), symbols.end(),
                     std::back_inserter( diffs ) );
```

You *can* use std::set as well, but you'll have to change the
inserter to `std::inserter( diffs, diffs.end() )`.

(Note that instead of sorting, you can keep the vectors sorted
during insertion, by using `std::lower_bound` to find the point
of insertion.  If you're filling them in one go, however, using
`std::sort` afterwards is probably more efficient.)